# Using a random integer to call an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I have a random integer e.g. randomInt and want to call a created button e.g. UIButton *button1, button2, button3 etc.

Will I be able to call the button as follows

```
NSString *buttonNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%d", randomInt];

[buttonNumber setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have a lot of these and it would decrease code amount dramatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the button assign a tag to the button like

```
button.tag = number
```

you can get the button later with

```
[[parentview viewWithTag:randomInt] setimage:...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create then Store your buttons in an NS(Mutable)Array then access them using:

```
UIButton* button = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:randomInt];
```

Comment: +1 Because this is a sensible approach that fixes the broken design.

Comment: Is this not creating double the amount of buttons? If I declare all my buttons, then add them to an array. To access them later, surely I dont create a new button?

Comment: you just get the reference back from the array and don't create a new object. But in this case you can simply work with tags.. they are there for such stuff. If you want to use an array you have to store it somewhere and make sure it's cleaned up properly.. maybe add the array in the parent view.. so you have to subclass uiview for it. With tags you don't need any extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

If the `UIButton`s are properties of your `self` object, you can do it like this:

```
[[self valueForKey:buttonNumber] setImage:...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use the **tags** with the button. It will help you a lot and it will reduce the code than you currently are using.

-hAPPY iCODING...